# Mac shell change default

Tags: macos, bash, shell

My default shell on the Mac is set to 
`/bin/bash`

However when I try see my alias settings it is blank. I have to type

```
bash
```

before they show up. 
After typing bash I still have the same shell as before, I check this by typing

```
which $SHELL
```

The result is always

```
/bin/bash
```

So why do I have to type bash before I can get my alias and environment from my **~/.bashrc** file

Answer (score 3):

The shell created when you open Terminal is a "login shell".  As a result, it will run `.bash_profile` if it exists; if not, it will try `.bash_login` and `.profile`, in that order.  It won’t run `.bashrc` unless you explicitly execute it from your `.bash_profile` (or `.bash_login` or `.profile`).

Comment: To add, `~/.bashrc` is only executed when the shell -is- interactive and when the shell is -not- invoked as a login shell. See [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). +1 btw.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`.

See [this article](http://smallthingsfloat.com/2013/03/30/bash_profile-or-bashrc-in-os-x/) for a deeper explanation, including suggestions for what to do when running on multiple Unixes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.bashrc
```

Terminal and iTerm 2 invoke bash as a login shell (which reads `.bash_profile` but not `.bashrc`), but for example tmux and the shell mode in Emacs invoke bash as a non-login shell (which reads `.bashrc` but not `.bash_profile`).